# .bashrc alias not working

Tags: bash, alias, bashrc

I have set up a few aliases in my `.bashrc` file, like the following:

```
alias ras='rails server'
alias res='redis-server'
alias rc='rails console'
alias be='bundle exec'

# git alias's are as follows
alias gs='git status'
alias gc='git commit'
alias go='git checkout'
alias ga='git add -p'
```

But when I try them out, `gs` opens up ghostscript, and `go master` returns

```
:~/Work/boogle[master]$ go master
The program 'go' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install golang-go
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. How can I make my aliases work?

Comment: Did you reload the file (`. ~/.bashrc`) after editing it?

Comment: If you do lots of changes to the `rc` file, as I suspect you will, you could be helped by an alias like this: `alias bup="hash -r; unalias -a; source ~/.bashrc"`. The third part is the most important one. Faster to type than the `source` (or `.`) command with the filepath. Or even better, put it in a script (i.e., another file) so it will still work even though you break the `rc` file (e.g., by a typo). Or, you could put that line **first** in `.bashrc`, that would be sort of the same.